# MailKit.IMapFolder: Method Search not found in type

Tags: .net, mailkit

I'm trying to check an inbox for an automation in both Windows and Linux, my method works fine in windows but not linux. Not sure what's going on, I can't find anyone else hitting this error.

In debugging I've narrowed it down to the Search method. I've tried mailkit 2.0.6 and 2.7.0 and .net 4.5.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Windows

`client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.SubjectContains("Automation Test Schedule Subject: 6/19/2020 4:57:04 PM"));`
`{11234}
    Count: 1
    IsReadOnly: false
    SortOrder: Ascending
    Validity: 0
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable`

Linux (ubuntu)

`client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.SubjectContains("Automation Test Schedule Subject: 6/19/2020 5:36:12 PM"));`
`Method 'Search' not found in type 'MailKit.IMailFolder'.`

Code

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
    {
        // connect to email client
        client.Connect(RandomOutlookAccnt);
        client.Authenticate(EmailAddress, Password);
        client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    client.Idle(cts.Token);

    var query = SearchQuery.SubjectContains(emailSubject);

    // search unique ids of the emails in inbox 
    var uids = client.Inbox.Search(query);
    var items = client.Inbox.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);


    . . . other stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation here is that your program on Linux is loading the wrong MailKit assembly.

Make sure that you bundle your program & run it with the exact same MailKit version that you compiled it with.